# Laravel application error 500 from SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, xampp

I have a laravel application in xampp with php 7, when I want to login I get an error 500, if I check the error_log in the storage folder, I see that it is the following error:

```
[2021-04-16 23:36:32] live.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = admin and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)
{"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = admin and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1) at 
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\p2\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\p2\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:326)
```

This is my first time whit laravel, I don't know how to resolve this issue, the code of the lines 326 and 664 are the next:

326

```
public function select($query, $bindings = [], $useReadPdo = true)
{
    return $this->run($query, $bindings, function ($query, $bindings) use ($useReadPdo) {
        if ($this->pretending()) {
            return [];
        }

        // For select statements, we'll simply execute the query and return an array
        // of the database result set. Each element in the array will be a single
        // row from the database table, and will either be an array or objects.
        $statement = $this->prepared($this->getPdoForSelect($useReadPdo)
                          ->prepare($query));

        $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings));

        $statement->execute();

        return $statement->fetchAll();
    });
}
```

664. Is only the catch of teh error, maybe could be usefull

```
protected function runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)
{
   
    try {
        $result = $callback($query, $bindings);
    }

    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new QueryException(
            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        );
    }
```

I received this application from a company that has me as an intern, but they didn't give me any more help or guidance, they just want it to work.
I appreciate any comments that can help me solve it.

Comment: It means the `username` isn't a column in the `user` table. Did you read the error to mean something different?

Comment: All I whant to know is why? if the database in phpmyadmin dont give me any error.

Comment: Prove it, include `show create table users` by editing it into your question.